# Word or sentence to describe a process

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or sentence to describe a process in formal terms. A process that is not an "Automated process" or "Manual Process" but somewhere in between. A word or sentence if you must, for example, a hand-operated process. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can describe it as  a ***[semi-automated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/semi-automated)***  process:

> - partially automated.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: Any other word without sticking to Automated ?

Comment: @GeraldGray- Semi-manual, would be a less common option, or semi-automatic.

Answer (score 0):

A `machine/software assisted`    process ?

Answer (score -2):

At your place I would write as below **[1] Semi-Automated.**
                           OR

**[2]".. by use of some of both: brain and brawn;we mean hand and machine.
In fact at the end of day each item we make is made by hand. 
If you asked me, we would say: Aren't machines made by man after all?"**
Kindly let me have your feed back fast and oblige.
Did you like the suggestion? It will make me happy.
{ look for defn. of brawn below:
brawn  (brôn)
Share:
n.
1. Solid and well-developed muscles, especially of the arms and legs.
2. Muscular strength and power.
3. Chiefly British The meat of a boar.
4. Headcheese.
[Middle English, muscle, from Old French braon, meat, of Germanic origin; see bhreu- in the Appendix of Indo-European roots.]
The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition copyright ©2015 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.}
https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=brawn&submit.x=23&submit.y=30

Comment: Hi @Abhilaaj. Welcome to ELU. As with all stackexchange sites, we are a question and answer site, not a discussion site. Hence a question should stand on its own and each answer should stand on its own. Answers should not have "chat" in them, or solicit responses. Hence please keep comments such as *"Kindly let me have your feed back fast and oblige. Did you like the suggestion? It will make me happy."* out of your posts.

Comment: Your answer [1] is no different from [Josh61's](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/305529/91730), and your answer [2] seems to be a long comment and not an actual suggestion for wording. Hence this answer isn't providing anything currently, in my opinion.

Comment: I beg to disagree.Semi- Automated is a catchier word. Let us await for compliance from the actual user. My answer is out of the box. Let us be receptive to creativity please.

Comment: "Semi-Automated is a catchier word"? Catchier than what? Than Josh61's suggestion of "semi-automated"?